# How to make a ListView act as an EditText

Tags: android, listview, interactive

I am developing an application for Android, and for that I am trying to make a ListView act in such a way, that when a user presses an empty entry, he can start typing text directly into that empty entry, and that when the user touches any other part of the screen, it is saved. Is there a way to do this? I was thinking of using onClick somehow, but I have no concrete approach.

Comment: Why not make a list of EditTexts and populate them programmatically, and then save when they lose focus?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is one basic, general approach:

1. For each row of the ListView, create a layout that has a visible TextView and a EditText with the visibility set to `gone`.
2. Use an onClickListener for each row to swap the visibilities of the TextView and EditText (respectively, `gone` and `visible`) when the row is selected.
3. Track the `active` row for clicks to another row or background.
4. When the `active` row changes, set the value of the EditText to the TextView and return them to their original visible states.

Comment: Thanks, this looks like a solid approach!

Answer (score 0):

Other approach that could be taken is using the View.OnFocusChangeListener and the TextWatcher   you can get more detail about them here http://developer.android.com/reference/packages.html